# Access VPN subnet from another PC in local(another) subnet

Tags: vpn, subnet, local

I have two PC in local subnet (192.168.0.0). One of them have connected through VPN to another subnet(10.0.0.0).

```
[192.168.0.0]
| - - PC1
| - - PC2 - - vpn - - [10.0.0.0]
Router -- [Internet]
```

Is there any way to get access to [10...] subnet for PC1 from local subnet?

Comment: Only if PC2 can act as a router; and even then, it would be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Following things need to be set up:

1. PC2 must be set up to forward packets between interfaces
2. On PC1 you need to set up routes so that it forwards traffic with destination is `10.0.0.0/24` to PC2.
3. On router at `10.0.0.0/24` network, you need to configure routes so that packets destined to `192.168.0.0/24` subnet are forwarded via PC2.